# Write failed: Broken pipe (in Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have the broken-pipe problem while using `ssh` to another Linux server (after idling for about 5-10 mins):

> Write failed: Broken pipe

Interestingly, I started to have this problem after upgrading my computer to Ubuntu 10.04, while the Linux server remains unchanged. I also tried to `ssh` from an OpenSUSE 11.2 machine, and it doesn't have any problem ...

Any clue?

Comment: Same problem , after idling ssh returns Write Filed Broken pipe.

Answer (score 5):

I think it could be a case of routers/firewalls/etc forcibly disconnecting your idle sessions.

Try using a 'keepalive' when you connect

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes
```

Note: there's definitely several other ways to set up keepalives on an ssh connection, server side or client side. Above is a straightforward client-side one.

hth

Comment: also try playing with the ServerAliveInterval option - ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30